# Cloudbuild - how to set a variable, looping multiples paths (folders)

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-build

i am trying to configure a variable in this case _PATH using cloudbuild. I've multiple paths (folders) on my github repo with tf files, and want to the terraform recognize any change that have been made on any folder  at the moment to push and trigger.

I was wondering if there is any way to looping values ​​separated by "comma" on trigger options and then use "for" in bash script.., or perhaps exists another better way that i dont really know yet,

Thanks for the help!

[code cloudbuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmMXi.jpg)

[cloudbuild sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI12Y.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the code to the question instead of a screenshot? It is hard to reproduce anything unless there is some code that can be used to test.

Comment: Does it a Google Cloud issue or a Terraform issue?

Comment: Hi, this is a cloudbuild requirement using terraform. I am trying to setting up a way to set the variable _PATH as you can see in the "cloudbuild sample image above" using multiple PATHS (folders), i want to the terraform recognize any change that have been made on any folder at the moment to push and trigger. I dont know if its possible unfortunately :(. 
Above you can see the "code cloudbuild" that i am using but is not working at the moment. 

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I haven't found a way yet to set variables at the `cloudbuild.yaml` level.

Note `CloudBuild` was originally called `Cloud Container Builder`, which is why it acts differently than other CI/CD tools.

I think there may be another way to get the behavior you want though:

1. Implement the `bash looping logic` in a script (ie. `sh/run_terraform_applys.sh`), and create a Dockerfile for it in your repo:

```
FROM hashicorp/terraform:1.0.0

WORKDIR /workspace

COPY sh/                           /workspace/sh/
COPY requirements.txt              /workspace/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN . sh/run_terraform_applys.sh

COPY .                            /workspace/
RUN . sh/other_stuff_to_do.sh
```

2. Use the cloud-builders image to build your image and as a consequence the `docker build` will run `sh/run_terraform_applys.sh` within the Docker image (You can `push` your image to GCR to allow for layer-caching):

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: 
      - '-c'
      - |-
        # Build Dockerfile
        docker build -t ${MY_GCR_CACHE}  --cache-from ${MY_GCR_CACHE} -f cicd/Dockerfile .
        docker push ${MY_GCR_CACHE}
    id: 'Run Terraform Apply'
    waitFor: ['-']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!